# Save file In a different folder in vim

Tags: windows, vim

I'm working with several files in gvim in Windows 7. I need to test the files (Python scripts) in linux. So apart from their original location I want to also save the files in a folder called `linux`. I want to do this with new files that I will be creating/modifying. That's why I want to use a mapping with the `%` sign to get the name of the current file Into the new path.
The problem I'm having is that the `%` sign is escaped with a backslash, so this doesn't work :

```
:w C:\projects\linux\%:t
```

Being the original location:

```
C:\projects\foo\
```

Is there a simple way to just save the current file in a different folder? (I have read that the `%` sign is a filename character, so I could erase it from the string `isfname` and it should work but I think I am making it more complicated than what it really is.)

Comment: Using backward slashes in a path is a really stupid idea, even on Windows (which, despite having to be different to every other operating system, will happily accept forward slashes).

Comment: @James: Indeed. And `vim` will _never_ expand `%` to the "filename" meaning when it is preceded by a backslash -- even if you try to use \\ to escape the backslash!

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: not true. Windows uses backslashes, so you should use backslashes in general. There are certainly some things that don't work properly with forward slashes (to take a trivial example, directory/filename completion in Command Prompt, but there are some more important ones somewhere; I just can't remember any at present).

Comment: I didn't know I could use forward slashes. Now that makes it much more easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this sort of thing fairly automatically using the `autocmd` feature.

The following (untested) line in your platform's equivalent of `~/.vimrc` will update a copy of a file when `gvim` makes modifications:

```
" clear commands
autocmd!
" when writing buffers, save a copy -- see :help filename-modifiers
autocmd BufWritePost c:/path/to/source/directory w %:t
```

The `:t` will take just the tail of the pathname; if you're working with multi-level directories, perhaps `:p:.` would be better. See the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, late to the party, but you could also use the workaround

```
:exe 'w C:\projects\linux\' . expand('%:t')
```

Answer (score 1):

My recollection is that you can escape the backslash by doubling it (but I'm not on Windows at present so I can't confirm it immediately). You don't need to escape them all, just the one which is causing trouble:

```
:w C:\projects\linux\\%:t
```

Comment: `:help cmdline-special`: _To avoid the special meaning of `%` and `#` insert a backslash before it. Detail: The special meaning is always escaped when there is a backslash before it, no matter how many backslashes._. Silly backslashes. :)

Comment: @sarnold: that's bad design. Ah well. I guess you could just use a forward slash for the last one, then.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the last backslash to a forward slash it will work:

```
:w C:\projects\linux/%:t
```